# Botão voltar fecha app

Tags: android

Tenho uma activity principal(MainActivity), que contém uma lista e um NavigationDrawer, quando clico na opção cadastro é chamada essa tela:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PessoasActivity.class));
```

E funciona normalmente, mas as vezes quando clico na opção de voltar da actionbar ele fecha o app, isso acontece mais quando efetuo a operação de salvar as informações no banco. Quando clico na opção de voltar do emulador e tmb no aparelho e fecha o app.

Meu AndroidManifest, registro do menu(MainActivity) e do cadastro(PessoasAcitivity):

```
<activity
        android:name="com.aplicacao.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true" >
    </activity>
<activity
        android:name="com.aplicacao.app.PessoasActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pessoas" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.aplicacao.app.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

[image: Imagem do app]

Comment: Thiago, tem certeza que não é por causa do atributo `noHistory="true"` em sua `MainActivity`? Com esse atributo, a `MainActivity` não fica no `BackStack` ao iniciar outra `Activity`, causando o problema.

Comment: Vou retirar e testar.

Comment: Deu certo, como faço para marcar seu comentário como resposta?

Comment: Vou criar uma resposta e poderá aceita-lá.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está no uso do atributo `noHistory="true"`. Removê-lo resolverá o problema.

De acordo com a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist), usar essa flag é o mesmo que chamar `finish` ao iniciar qualquer `Activity` com o contexto da sua `MainActivity`. Com isso a `MainActivity` não permanece no `BackStack`, sendo que ao usar a navegação de volta, seja pelo *Back Button* ou pelo *Home Indicator*, a `MainActivity` não será restaurada.